# Ionic vue router animation for ios doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I just created a new ionic vue app (tabs template) and noticed after swapping mode to `ios` the routing animations are gone.
With `md` everything works fine.

My `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" mode="ios">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>
```

Also when routing this error pops up in the console

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at animateLargeTitle (ios.transition-48010460.js?2f12:1)
    at createLargeTitleTransition (ios.transition-48010460.js?2f12:1)
    at iosTransitionAnimation (ios.transition-48010460.js?2f12:1)
    at eval (index-c3ff7f2e.js?9897:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js?f530:102)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js?f530:83)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js?f530:73)
```

My versions:

```
Ionic CLI       : 6.14.1  
Ionic Framework : @ionic/vue 5.6.6  
Vue             : 3.0.0
Vue-router      : 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the collapsible large title was configured incorrectly.

This is how it should look like:

```
<ion-header :translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title> {{ greeting }} </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button router-link="/test" routerDirection="forward" color="dark">
        <ion-icon :icon="timeOutline" size="large" />
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content :fullscreen="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar class="tab-toolbar">
      <ion-title size="large"> {{ greeting }} </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
</ion-content>
```

Also here is the repo that i used for testing: https://github.com/NBprojekt/ionic-vue-routing
And an working [example](https://nbprojekt.github.io/ionic-vue-routing/test)